# probability of not getting same number twice in a row after n die rolls

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, dice

Having rolled a die $n$ times, I want to determine the probability of not getting any number twice in a row. If I wanted the probability of not getting any number three times in a row, I could use the following recursion:
$$p_n=\frac{5}{6}p_{n-1}+\frac{5}{36}p_{n-2},$$
as the streak is broken $5/6$ of the time, meaning we just need to multiply by the corresponding probability for one fewer trials, and the streak is continued $1/6$ of the time, so we need to break it with probability $5/6$ and multiply by the corresponding probability for two fewer trials. However, I am having difficulties applying this method to the seemingly easier length-two streak case. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of not getting two in a row in $n$ trials is $5/6$ times the probability of not getting two in a row in $n-1$ trials.

*Remark:* A related problem, the probability of not getting two of a *specified* number, like $4$, twice in a row is harder. We get a second order recurrence rather than a first-order recurrence.

*Added:* We find a recurrence for the "no two $4$'s in a row problem. There are $6^n$ equally likely sequences of $n$ tosses. Let $a_n$ be the number of sequences with no two $4$'s in a row. A good sequence of length $n$ either (i) does not end in a $4$ or (ii) ends in a $4$.

The Type (i) sequences are obtained by appending a non-$4$ to any good sequence of length $n-1$, So there are $5a_{n-1}$ of them.

The Type (ii) sequences are obtained by appending a $4$ to a good sequence of length $n-1$ that does not end in a $4$. These can be obtained by appending a non-$4$ to a good sequence of length $n-2$, so there are $5a_{n-2}$ of them.

We have obtained the recurrence $a_n=5a_{n-1}+5a_{n-2}$.

Comment: I guess my problem is making an analogy with the question: what is the probability of getting no two consecutive heads in $n$ coin tosses, the answer here is given by the recurrence $p_n=0.5p_{n-1}+0.25p_{n-2}$

Comment: The proper analogy is then I think the problem I mentioned in the remark. The no two in a row (which two unspecified) is as you saw much simpler. If you experience trouble, I can add to the remark.

Comment: ok thanks I think I see now, so the answer to your problem of no two consecutive $4$'s in $n$ tosses would be given by the recursion $p_n=\frac{5}{6}p_{n-1}+\frac{5}{36}p_{n-2}$, because we either start with any number other than $4$ in the first case or start with $4$ in the second case. Does this seem correct?

Comment: I will add to the remark in $10$ minutes or so.

Comment: ok thanks for the extended answer, just one last thing which is unclear to me: if we start with a number other than $4$ with probability $5/6$, we just     need to have a sequence of length $n-1$ with no two consecutive $4$'s with probability $p_{n-1}$, and if we start with $4$ with probability $1/6$, we need any number other than $4$ in the next roll with probability $5/6$ and finally a sequence of length $n-2$ with no two consecutive $4$'s with probability $p_{n-2}$, So is my probability recurrence equivalent to your counting recurrence?

Comment: They lead to the same answer. Since the probability $p_n$  is $a_n/6^n$, you can let $a_k=6^kp_k$ and then my recurrence becomes $6^np_n=(5)(6^{n-1})p^{n-1}+(5)(6^{n-2})p_{n-2}$. Divide both sides by $6^n$ and we get your recurrence. For no good reason, I thought a counting recurrence might be intuitively clearer than a probability recurrence.

Comment: thanks man, it is clear now. So finally the probability of not getting any number three times in a row is also equal to the probability of not getting a specific number two times in a row when we roll a die $n$ times.

Comment: actually the probabilities will be different due to the base cases, but what I meant is the recursions are the same

Comment: The recurrence for the no three of any kind in a row looks correct. But I am sure about these things only after writing out a solution.